# Query - SELECT BOX,COUNT(*) from TABLE WHERE GROUP BY

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to MongoDB and have a table BOXTABLE like below

```
boxname
time_created
box_data
```

Basically we are logging which box is sending what data and at what time. Assuming that the table has below data and now means current time:

```
BoxA,Now,'AAA'
BoxB,Now,'AAA'
BoxC,Now,'AAA'
BoxA,Now,'AAA'
BoxA,Now,'AAA'
BoxB,Now,'AAA'
BoxA,Now,'AAA'
BoxC,Now,'AAA'
BoxA,Now,'AAA'
BoxB,Now,'AAA'
```

So I need to get data like this:

```
BoxA - 5
BoxB - 3
BoxC - 2
```

Now my requirement is that is to create an alert in system if a box sends more request than a threshold values indicating probably something is wrong or suspicious from that box. Assuming the current **threshold value is 4** so I should get an alert for BoxA:

As such my requirement is to execute a query something like this:

```
SELECT BOXNAME,COUNT(BOX_DATA) FROM BOXTABLE WHERE time_create >= now and time_create < now + 600
```

I tried the same but n ot sure why its is not working:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{"$group" : {"$id" : "$boxname", count:{"$box_data":1}}, time_created: {"$gte":start,"$lt":end}}])
```

Where start and end are like below:

```
start = int(time.time())
end = start + 600
```

Is my code correct - when I run the I get below error

```
NameError: name 'count' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to filter the range as well as [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) here. And the correct way to "count" is using [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) i.e `{ "sum": 1 }` for every "grouped" value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
      "time_created": { "$gte":start, "$lt":end }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$boxname",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

The [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is the "filter", equivalent to `"WHERE"`, as the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is to `"GROUP BY"`.

As a "pipeline" each stage gives it output to the next, in order. That is the main point of thinking to adapt to. Filter first, then "group".

If you then for example wanted a `"HAVING"` clause, you would then similarly [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) "after" the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
      "time_created": { "$gte":start, "$lt":end }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$boxname",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 4 } } }
])
```

And that is the same as saying `"HAVING count > 4"` on the end of a SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks it helped but one more small help - how to check for the threshold values also - means I need to list data in-between time range and for record (boxnames) whose number of records in results more than 4 as per my example?

Comment: @Prakash I belive you mean a `"HAVING"` clause. In the future though, when you have additional questions to what you actually ask then [Ask a new Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - it helped a lot. Thanks for the directions and details given - I would follow the rule